# Full or Incremental User Profile Sync needed?

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync

Our client uses SharePoint Server 2013. We created a People directory, but the problem is that for many employees the job title in the  search results is shown twice: as in "Job title: job title job title" (so right after each other).

When I looked at the User Profile properties I noticed that both the properties "Title" and "Job title" are mapped to the "title" field in Active Directory.

We deleted the mapping of the "Job title" field with the AD, hoping this will solve the issue.
Question: does this action require an incremental or full syncronization of the User Profile Service to take effect? Is this the right approach to solve our issue?

Answer (score 2):

When ever you make changes like "changing the mapping of property or adding a new mapping or removing,or applying exclusion filter". You have to run the full sync followed by an incremental sync.

Answer (score 0):

When you change attribute mapping in UPSA you have to do a full sync which takes into account all current mappings. This is true both for removing and adding mapping as well as changing direction from import to export.